# Can't Login to Database in MSQL from another computer - Reason: Could not open database "SSISDB". [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Tags: sql-server

I've tried to set up connecting to a SQLserver database from another computer (The DB is hosted in a another computer in the same network).

I can confirm that I have completed the following:
    1. I have set up TCP and UDP Port
    2. I am able to ping the Host computer through IP and Computer Name (Thru CMD)
    3. All Services, (SQLServer, SQLServer Broswer) are all running
    4. My log-in credentials is accurate.
    5. I am able to login to the SQLserver on the host machine but not thru a client machine

I am getting a basic error message from the client side (can't find server) but on the host side, I am seeing this error in the logs.

> DOMAIN\MACHINE_NAME$'. Reason: Could not open database "SSISDB".
>   [CLIENT: ]

I'm not sure why I am not able to open SSISDB as I am logging in with the credentials of the owner of the DB. I'm not sure why SSISDB is needed in the first place as I am simply just logging in. I don't have any batch jobs or any jobs that has anything to do with SSISDB

I am really stuck and I tried searching other sources but I haven't found a post pertaining to my problem.

I have tried:
1. Set up TCP/UDP connection
2. Opening Firewall to Ports
3. Setting DB to multiuser
4. Connecting through TCP on Host Machine (I was able to)

Comment: try run your ssis via sql server agent job, using our credentials

Comment: how do you go about doing that? Than you

Comment: visit this link. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9069/deploy-and-schedule-an-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-package-step-by-step/

Comment: Please post the actual message from the client side. There might be two different errors here. What user does the client connect as? What does your connection string look like? What tool are you using to connect with?

Comment: TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to 192.168.16.100.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1326)

The user name or password is incorrect

Comment: I created a new user and password on the host machine as sysadmin. I just tried logging on and it also said the username and password is incorrect. Is there something I need to do to the username?

Answer (score 0):

You can try these tw options:

1. Change the service account of SQL Server to be a domain account or a
   Group Managed Service Account and grant permissions to this
   account.
2. Add DOMAIN\MACHINNAME$ as a login on the target server, this time be
   careful to include the dollar name. This is the machine account for
   the server, and this account is used when a service running under a
   local account access another server.